# Can I do anything to make this electric piano work?

Tags: voltage, dc, connector, current-source, adapter

I have an electric piano but I don't have the power supply.  It has a barrel connector with a negative tip, and wants 12 VDC, 1.5 A.

I have a power supply that is 12 VDC, 2.67 A, but it has a positive tip.

Is this supply sufficient?  Can I modify my power supply in any way allowing it to meet the specifications? Sorry, I don't know much about circuitry and I'm hoping someone would be able to help.

Comment: You might cut the DC_power cable and swap the black-white wires; I presume the polarity is marked along one side with a white stripe. The current ratings of 1.5Amp, versus 2.67Amp, should not be a problem. But I make no promises. No warrantee expressed or implied.

Comment: It might sound like a stupid question, but why not just buy a suitable power supply? You even get units with a choice of tips that you can use in either polarity by just plugging the tip in to the unit with a 180 degree rotation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. All you need to do is cut, swap and splice the conductors of the power supply. That's all that is needed to change a center positive to a center negative dc connector.

The alternative is to buy a modular power supply, like those offered by RadioShack with replaceable heads. You can simply choose the right size head and plug it in so that it is center negative.

As far as the current goes, the amperage listed on a power supply is the max it can supply. A device will only pull what it needs, so having a supply that can offer more is not a problem. As long as the voltage matches,  and the amperage is the same or greater, or should work.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a power supply that is 12 VDC, 2.67 A, but it has a positive
>   tip.

Just buy one of these: -

[image]

They come in all shapes and sizes.

Comment: Do negative tip 5.5 mm barrel connectors usually have a 2.5 mm inner? And positive tip ones have a 2.1 mm inner? I found the former to be the case for a Brother H105 label printer and a small light table (for viewing transparencies) we have in the office.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I really do have no idea. This answer is all about finding a pice of wire that reverses the polarity. If not this one then there'll be others that do the job!

Comment: I just thought that someone with more experience might know, so the OP would be able to buy a 5.5 * 2.1 mm floating socket to 5.5 * 2.5 mm plug. Oh well...

Answer (score 2):

If you go to a distributor with a wide range such as Digikey and do a parametric search you can find a few supplies that will work. Eg.

[image]

So long as the max output current is **equal or better** than the requirement, and the other requirements match (polarity, plug style, mains plug style, mains voltage, output voltage) you should be okay.

Or just cut and splice the cord you have, but it will tend not to be as strong as the original.

Answer (score 1):

If the barrel connector on the power supply fits the piano, it would be fine to cut off the tip and reverse the wires, but be warned: Sometimes these power supplies, instead of using two wires, use a single wire with a shield. If this is the case, you'll have to get creative when crossing the conductors. Heat shrink tubing is your friend.

It should go without saying that you should test the fit of the connectors while the power supply is *unplugged* :)

Answer (score -1):

Most barrel connectors I encounter these days are standardized for CCTV use, and have positive centers and predictable dimensions.

Matching older barrel connectors is a crapshoot.  Very often it is better to replace the receptacle.

It sounds like your power supply has more than enough current, if you are sure about it - of course, you never know if any random supply might sag in voltage when run near their highest current ratings.

Might want to try this with a laboratory power supply first.  Get in behind the barrel receptacle and just clip on power wires right there, )if it is accessible) and make sure your supply can provide enough current.

Comment: "Most barrel connectors these days are standardized for CCTV use" - Do you have any evidence to support this claim?

Comment: Fair enough, @Hayman.  I edited my answer based on your comment.  Thank you for explaining the downvote.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted